# Export PostgreSQL database in sql format

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, резервное-копирование

Я пытаюсь сделать бэкап базы данных которая на postgresql, хостинг (heroku)
Но при попытке скачать я скачиваю базу данных в зашифровоном виде.
Мне нужно получить дамп в формате sql файла, как именно это сделать?

> pg_dump -U postgres -N -x -b -O --inserts -d [имя вашей базы] > /tmp/base-dump-filename.sql

В гугле я рылся много но так и не понял. Вроде бы подсказали этот скрипт но как его правильно использовать на heroku? (Windows 8.1)

Comment: Указанная команда (хотя меня весьма удивило отсутствие ошибки за `-N` (aka `--exclude-schema`) без указания собственно схемы) именно толпу sql запросов и создаст. В чём выражается "зашифрованность" данных?

Comment: @Мелкий скачивает файл latest.dump, там строки в виде:

`5047 444d 5001 0d00 0408 0101 0100 0000
0028 0000 0000 2c00 0000 000a 0000 0000`

Comment: @Мелкий Я в этом плохо разбираюсь, пытался сделать все с помощью поисковика, но у меня ничего не вышло. Поэтому прошу помощи у вас

Comment: "latest.dump" как-то совсем не похоже на "base-dump-filename.sql". Что именно вы скачиваете? Может быть какой-то не тот файл который создавали?

Comment: У меня сейчас в папке только файл latest.dump, скриптом я не пользовался еще тк-как не знаю как его правильно использовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по [документации этого heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) получить бекап базы `postgresql` возможно только в формате `PostgreSQL custom database dump` архива.

Необходимо импортировать этот дамп в любую подконтрольную вам базу `postgresql` через штатную утилиту `pg_restore`, пример запуска есть в упомянутой документации:

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U [имя пользователя] -d [имя вашей базы] latest.dump
```

После этого, имея уже нормальный консольный доступ, возможно вызвать `pg_dump` для снятия дампа базы в `plain` формате, представляющий собой последовательность SQL команд. (это формат по-умолчанию)

```
pg_dump -U [имя пользователя] -x -b -O --inserts -d [имя вашей базы] > /tmp/base-dump-filename.sql
```

Если дамп надо переносить на другой postgresql - лучше оставить `custom` формат, как более компактный. Или хотя бы использовать `copy` для импорта данных, т.е. не использовать ключ `--inserts`. `copy` существенно быстрее.

Comment: Огромное спасибо.