# Работа с postgre | Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, импорт, dump

Ребята подскажите пожалуйста у меня на компьютере есть дамп data.dump этот дамп нужно залить на хероку как это сделать? heroku gp:backups:restore восстанавливает только бэкапы на серверах хероку а мне нужно мой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вам ли я недавно как раз [давал ссылку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/834954/203622) на [документацию этого heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) по экспорту базы? Импорт базы описан ровно там же.

Импортировать можно только `custom` формат дампа, пример вызова `pg_dump` есть в документации:

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump
```

Затем этот дамп необходимо разместить куда-нибудь, откуда его можно получить по HTTP без авторизации.

Затем вызвать импорт указав ссылку на этот файл:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore 'ссылка на дамп' DATABASE_URL
```

В конце обязательно удалите дамп с того места куда вы его загрузили.

Comment: Спасибо, а вы не знаете куда можно загрузить?

Comment: Нет, не знаю, где нынче прямые ссылки дают. Документация s3 советует.